# How to calculate wind generated by a simple thermal gradient?

Tags: temperature, meteorology

It's something I feel like I never came across in an obvious way in being taught meteorology, though perhaps I just overlooked it, or how to apply a specific equation, back then...

Let's just go idealized and define to have two separate sealed homogeneous rooms, and then you open the door between them.  How do you calculate what magnitude of "wind" will form?

Or if the location and size of the gap complicates things too much, just consider the entire boundary to be instantaneously removed (and minimal impacts from removing the boundary).

It has been a while since the intensive physics foundations... but I'd think it'd cause a circulation, with cool air moving into the warmer room at low-levels and warm air moving into the cooler room aloft (much like the [classic grade school demonstration](https://youtu.be/Ak9CBB1bTcc?t=57), or a front), and so probably involves depth in some way, properties of the fluid like heat transfer coefficient and viscosity, and of course the magnitude of the gradient.

But is there a fairly straightforward equation/method, perhaps at a simplicity similar to Newtonian cooling for solids, that can be applied and easily solved?